# Django rest_auth - how to add custom password validation rules

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, passwords, django-rest-auth

Can someone explain how to alter the default password validation rules for Django's rest_auth library?

I imagine this can be done by copying the existing serializers and adding custom validation there. ([Link to rest_auth serializer documentation](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration)) I could dive into this myself, but I think this will cost me a lot of time, and it would be nice if someone can give me at least an explanation on a beginner level.

Some people may think that I am lazy to even ask such a question, but please let's leave personal opinions out of this. I am quite a beginner programmer, diving into a lot of different technologies. A bit of help here and there can safe quite some time.

Besides that I am quite sure there will be others who will be looking for this information.

On my (React) frontend I am using the following validation rules, and I would like the backend to have the same:

Password must contain at least:
 - one uppercase letter (A-Z)
 - one lowercase letter (a-z)
 - one of the following characters: !@#$&*
 - one number (0-9)
Password must be at least 10 characters long
Password can not contain other characters than the ones above

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I found out that I can use Django's build in functionality for password validation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation

Password validators can be used / created, and pointed to in the Django settings. These validators will be used by rest_auth as well. The above link to the Django documentation explains this very well.